# How to disable _force-cgi-redirect_ in PHP compilation?

Tags: php

I am working with PHP 7 (or trying to) and am at wits end trying to find a way to disable the **force-cgi-redirect** feature. No matter what I try, it seems to still always build the *php-cgi* binary with that option.

I've tried adding the following line to both **php.ini-development** and **php.ini-development** in the project directory:

```
cgi.force_redirect = 0
```

That didn't work - so I also added the **--disable-force-cgi-redirect** to the *./configure* command line - and that also didn't work.

I've Googled and Googled for a solution -- and came up with nothing but the first of the two things I tried and (when I got very specific) also the second of the two things I tried.

I am aware of the security risks of disabling this "feature" -- but the context for which I need PHP 7 is one where FastCGI does not apply.

As the server's default is PHP 5, the only way I can work on PHP 7 is if I can do it as a CGI script in which the first line is:

```
#! /my/home/directory/local/bin/php-cgi
```

.. and where PHP 7 is at that location because I compiled it with the **--prefix= /my/home/directory/local"** option - and I need it to run, once invoked that way, the same way as it would were it invoked by the server directly.

However, I am prevented from doing this because, no matter what I do, I can't seem to disable the **force-cgi-redirect** feature.

I can get the script to run if it is invoked with the **/my/home/directory/local/bin/php** interpreter rather than the **/my/home/directory/local/bin/php-cgi** interpreter - but this does not help me, as this solution results in PHP 7 behaving in the command-line manner (little, yet important differences, such as no header output).

**NOTE:** For testing purposes (so that I could see what was going wrong) I also attempted to write a CGI script similar to the following one (say it is called "phptest.cgi"):

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""

/my/home/directory/local/bin/php-cgi phptest.php
```

That is how I found out that the problem was the **force-cgi-redirect** feature -- as before doing this, all I got was the nebulous notification that a server error had occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cgi.force_redirect` is a [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) (the PHP configuration file) option.

`php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` are suggested `php.ini` configurations. They're templates for a `php.ini` file, not `php.ini` itself: when PHP runs, it will not look for files by those names. If you want to set `php.ini` options, you need to make a file named, well, `php.ini`.

So, what you need to do is make a `php.ini` file (base it off the -development or -production file as appropriate), place it in [one of the search paths](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php), and modify it to have `cgi.force_redirect=0` in it.

Comment: Thanks, Andrea. :-) I followed your suggestion --- and it seems to work. :-) And thanks to the __--prefix= /my/home/directory/local__ build option, I have write access to the place where the configuration file goes. :-) Thanks. :-)